# Routes - how to display in url ID and the name of article?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I have the **Articles** controller and for displaying the respective article I use the basic routes - **example.com/articles/4**.

I would like to change this URL format to **example.com/4-article-name** or **example.com/article-name-4**.

Could anyone give me a tip, how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates(Railscast.com) seems to have done an episode that solves your problem:

```
/app/models/article.rb 
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
  end
end
```

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

Generally numbers on the beginning is the most elegant way, since in ruby it could be very easily converted to integer, for instance `'123-foo-bar'.to_i` will return `123`.
See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param you'll find how to change this mechanism.